# Disable maxGramSize for solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Tags: solr, sunspot, n-gram

Is it possible to disable `maxGramSize` for `solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory`?

Sunspot's Wiki article [Matching substrings in fulltext search](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Matching-substrings-in-fulltext-search) points to [Solr EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) . The only information Apache solr's Wiki has on `maxGramSize` is that by default its value is 1.

Is there some way of explicitly stating that there's no maximum gram size, or is the only possibility to set `maxGramSize` to a number far larger than I expect any individual word to have a length of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having a look at [the current code of the EdgeNGramTokenFilter](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_5_3_0/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/EdgeNGramTokenFilter.java) (Solr 5.3.0), no there is no such thing. But you can use 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (=2147483647) which is the maximum value for an int in Java.